# Do not lock up bash shell

Tags: bash, git-bash

If I have a shell command that hangs up the shell, something like `ng serve`, is there anyway to keep it from locking up the shell? I'm writing a shell script and want to include a command after something like this, but while it is still running.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command in the background:

```
ng serve &
```

Comment: Add `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end if you want to suppress the command's stdout/stderr.  Add `nohup` at the beginning if you want the command to keep running when you exit the current shell.

Comment: `nohup` is no longer needed in job control shells like bash, ksh, zsh, etc.